# browser px and css px

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

> HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./index.css">
</head>
<body>
    <div class="a">

    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

> CSS

```
* {
    margin:0;
}
.a {
    width: 400px;
    height: 200px;
    background-color: red;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 800px) {
    .a {
        width: 200px;
    }
}
```

When I resize browser, element div change to  width 200px, It always happened at about 880px(Chrome develper-tools).

Chrome develper-tools show 880px .

Chrome show 880px at Upper right corner, I can not capture it(it need resize browser then it show)

---

But style show it happened at 800px

[image]

---

why it is different?

Comment: We can't answer unless you show us a full working example, showing your CSS and your HTML . Thanks

Comment: @Martin, I try to edit that, I hoped it more clear.

Comment: I found something happened this.Open this through VsCode with Live Server extension.
Is this a bug?  
I open this from folder or web, it's responsive at right px.

Answer (score 0):

https://codepen.io/r0binxp/pen/PoNNbGJ try with this example, putting only `@media (max-width: 800px`

Comment: This is a comment not an answer